# MYSQL + PHP - обновление поля таблицы

Tags: php, mysql, запрос

Задача такая, в бд имеется поле, например, numbers, в котором хранятся числа через запятую (поле типа TINYTEXT)

Вот пример

```
numbers
1,2,4,21
3,5,8,9
11,10,6
```

На php у меня есть массив с числами, например $array = [1, 8, 10, 6]
Нужно составить запрос, который уберет все числа, которые есть в массиве в этом столбце numbers, а также уберет ненужные запятые, вообщем формат должен остаться корректным

Т.е. результат должен быть

```
2,4,21
3,5,9
11
```

Желательно без циклов и т.д одним запросом
Про JSON формат в MYSQL я знаю, здесь он не используется

Answer (score 0):

Приведенный способ явно не подойдет для регулярного использования.
Для одного числа можно сделать такой запрос:

```
UPDATE tableName
SET fieldName=TRIM(BOTH ',' FROM REPLACE(CONCAT(',', fieldName, ','), ',valueToRemove,', ','))
WHERE id=ID
```

где fieldName - название поля, valueToRemove - число, которое нужно заменить.
Для нескольких числел можно последовательно REPLACE вызвать.

Comment: Спасибо за решение

Comment: В случае если несколько одинаковых чисел идут подряд почему-то не срабатывает, это можно поправить

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b31028a51f933850bf794a3ccba3a01e